# How can I point to repository root directory in jest config file?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, monorepo, nx-monorepo

I have a monorepo managed by `nx`. I have a `jest.preset.js` file in the repository root directory. There is `Reporters` configuration in that file as below:

```
reporters: [
    'default',
    [
      '<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-junit',
      {
        outputDirectory: 'dist/',
        outputName: 'report.xml',
        uniqueOutputName: 'false',
        titleTemplate: '{classname}-{title}',
        ancestorSeparator: ' › ',
        usePathForSuiteName: 'true',
        includeConsoleOutput: 'true',
        suiteName: 'Test Report',
      },
    ]
  ],
```

The `jest-junit` is installed in the root of the repository `node_modules` folder. The project structure is as below:

```
packages/is-even
nx.json
package.json
jest.preset.js
jest.config.js
```

I got an error when I run `npx nx test is-even`. The `nx` command tries to look at `jest-junit` module from `is-even` package rather than the repo root. I have specified `<rootDir>` under `reporters` folder. but it doesn't make `nx` to look at root level. How can I make it look at root level rather than package level?

```
 NX   Could not resolve a module for a custom reporter.

     Module name: packages/is-even/node_modules/jest-junit
```